# Does Gollum know that he was once a hobbit?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

Gollum is crazy, we know that, but does he realize that he was once a hobbit who changed? Does he remember any of his former self especially when he meets Bilbo?

Comment: False premise: As I understand it, he wasn't *actually* ever a hobbit, just a hobbit-like creature.

Comment: @Martha He was a hobbit, at least ages ago, prior to his getting the Ring: http://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/24069/1027

Comment: @Martha he was a *kind* of hobbit, one of the three races I guess you'd call them, but not the one that Frodo and Bilbo are from.

Comment: Smeagol was a hobbit. The corruption of the ring turned him into the twisted creature now he is and provoked the emergence of Gollum, his second evilish personality. I'm not sure now, but I think there's a passage on the books where he has a briefly remembrance of his past life, however is Gandalf the first to inform Bilbo that Gollum belongs to it's own race.

Comment: @Martha Sméagol, which was Gollum's true name, was a [Stoor Hobbit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stoor#Divisions). Stoors were a kind of Hobbit, which means he was one.

Comment: Tale of Years for TA2463 confirms that Deagol at least *is* a Stoor.  Shadow of the Past confirms that his friend Smeagol is "of similar sort".  Smeagol may be related to a branch from the hobbit line, as the Shire had been occupied since TA1601 (862 years previous) or he may be an actual hobbit, but either way Deagol definitely *is* a hobbit.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

Whether he remembers being a hobbit/hobbit-like, he does remember where he came from:

Chapter 5, page 75:

> ... Gollum brought up memories of ages and ages and ages before, when
> he lived with his grandmother in a hole in a bank by a river, "Sss,
> sss, my preciouss," he said.  "Sun on the daisies it means, it does."
>
> But these ordinary above ground everyday sort of riddles were tiring
> for him.  Also they reminded him of days when he had been less lonely
> and sneaky and nasty, and that put him out of temper.

Chapter 5, page 76:

> But suddenly Gollum remember thieving from nests long ago, and
> sitting under the river bank teaching his grandmother, teaching his
> grandmother to suck -- "Eggses!" he hissed. "Eggses it is!"